# How to have a "Data Saved Successfully" message popup when data is saved?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on an Excel VBA for the first time and I have managed to create a user form data can be entered from. I am currently looking for a code that would pop up upon successful saving of the data saying "data has been saved successfully" or "error! data not saved". How can I do that?
Here is what I have so far

```
Private Sub cmdAddData_Click()
If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must select your full name", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
If ComboBox2.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must select the full name of your 1st nominee", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
If ComboBox3.Value = "" Then
     MsgBox "You must select the readiness level of your 1st nominee", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim AddNew As Range
Set wks = Sheet6
Set AddNew = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = ComboBox1.Value
AddNew.Offset(0, 8).Value = ComboBox2.Value
AddNew.Offset(0, 18).Value = ComboBox3.Value
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question and specify (exactly) what isn't working and what causes the error.

Comment: Use a `msgbox`? What exactly is the question?

Comment: I apologize. I meant a popup upon clicking the add data command button saying "data is successfully saved"

Comment: [MsgBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function) "your message" should do just about fine.

Comment: @LogicalBranch okay. sorry I will do that now.

Comment: A command button has a click event. Put a `msgbox` in it.

Comment: You did something odd when you attempted to paste code (which caused all of these `enter code here` to display). The best way to paste code is to just paste it as is, select it, and then either hit the code icon or use `Ctrl+K` to format it as code.

Comment: I apologize. I am new to this and I find myself making mistakes right and left

Comment: Stack Overflow's way of formatting code has never struck me as very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach:

```
Sub qwerty()
    s = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter a value", Type:=1)
    [A1] = s
    On Error GoTo issuewarning
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    MsgBox "data has been saved successfully"
    Exit Sub
issuewarning:
     MsgBox "error! data not saved"
     Exit Sub
End Sub
```